# (Android) Passing multidimensional array through intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, multidimensional-array, bundle

I want to pass a multidimensional array to an activity

multidimensional array:

```
double[][][] speed  = new double[][][]
{
    {
        { 15, 10 },
        { 16, 12 }
    },
    {
        { 14, 50 },
        { 18, 51 }
    }
};

Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("speed", speed);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LineChart.class);
myIntent.putExtra("speed", mBundle);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

And to receive it in another class (linechart class) i use:

```
private double[][][] _speed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get ALL the data!!!
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        this._speed = extras.getSerializable("speed");
    }

    setContentView(showLineChart());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Serializable to double[][][]
```

Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you AActivity and BActivity

In AActivity, declare variable and the following method:

```
private static double[][][] doubleVar;  
public static boolean[][][] getDoubleVar()
{
 return doubleVar;
}
```

Now assign the value to to doubleVar in AActivity.

Now from BActivity, you can access doubleVar like this: AActivity.getDoubleVar()

Answer (score 0):

You would have to cast it to `double[][][]`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get ALL the data!!!
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        this._speed = (double[][][]) extras.getSerializable("speed");
    }

    setContentView(showLineChart());
}
```